# Why does Android suggest functions outside of onCreate "can be private"?

Tags: android, kotlin

My activity looks like this:

```
class PlayerDetails : AppCompatActivity() {    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_details)
        ...
    }

    fun clearFields() { 
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}
```

When I hover over `clearFields()` Android studio suggests `Function clearFields could be private`. Why does it suggest this?

Comment: Thats because you are only using it inside this class . So it can be or should be private ..

Comment: check lints in android and how they work its usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not calling that function from any other class.
If the function is only called from within the activity, it can be private so other classes can't see it.
If you call it from another class like a fragment, then it wont suggest it as being private, as it knows it'll need to be public.